# Adding columns in mat-table using a condition

Tags: angular, mat-table

I need to construct a table following these requirements:

- At least have 4 columns: ClientId || Foo_Type || Foo 1 || Foo 2
- If more than three "Foo" in Foo_Chain, the table needs to grow like the following example
- ClientId || Foo_Type || Foo 1 || Foo 2 || Foo 3 || Foo 4

```
[
   {
      "clientId":"44",
      "Foo_Type":"XYZ",
      "Foo_Chain":[
         {
            "Imported":true,
            "Foo":"XYZ 1"
         },
         {
            "Imported":true,
            "Foo":"XYZ 2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "clientId":"44",
      "Foo_Type":"ABC",
      "Foo_Chain":[
         {
            "Imported":true,
            "Foo":"ABC 1"
         },
         {
            "Imported":true,
            "Foo":"ABC 2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "clientId":"44",
      "Foo_Type":"ASR",
      "Foo_Chain":[
         {
            "Imported":true,
            "Foo":"ASR 1"
         },
         {
            "Imported":true,
            "Foo":"ASR 2"
         },
         {
            "Imported":true,
            "Foo":"ASR 3"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "clientId":"44",
      "Foo_Type":"LOP",
      "Foo_Chain":[
         {
            "Imported":true,
            "Foo":"LOP 1"
         },
         {
            "Imported":true,
            "Foo":"LOP 2"
         },
         {
            "Imported":true,
            "Foo":"LOP 3"
         },
         {
            "Imported":true,
            "Foo":"LOP 4"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I have this HTML, but the mat table is static, and I don't know how to proceed to make this start growing if needed

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
          <ng-container matColumnDef="clientId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{'ClientId' | uppercase}} </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="data-column">
              {{element.clientID}}
            </td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="footype">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{'Foo_Type' | uppercase}} </th>
            <div fxLayout="row">
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="data-column">
                {{element.foo_Type}}
              </td>
            </div>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="footype1">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{'FooType1' | uppercase}} </th>
            <div fxLayout="row">
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="data-column">
              {{elemente.FooChain[0].Foo}}
              </td>
            </div>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="footype2">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{'FooType2' | uppercase}} </th>
            <div fxLayout="row">
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="data-column">
              {{elemente.FooChain[1].Foo}}
              </td>
            </div>
          </ng-container>
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns sticky: true"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be better to have one column and that one column split into sub columns to show all the content. Otherwise, what will you do if you first item has three foo chains and your second has two foo chains? Let an empty to column for the second item?

Comment: @TiagoSilva I can have an empty column, like the second item, this isn't a problem, I believe that using the solution with sub-columns would be a problem because of some individual behaviors

Comment: In this case your mat-table must have also dynamic columns. You need to set the columns to display using typescript. I will add a short example.

Answer (score 1):

```
 export class TableDynamicColumnsExample {
      displayedColumns: string[] = ['client', 'foo_type'];
      columnsToDisplay: string[] = this.displayedColumns.slice();
      data: PeriodicElement[] = ELEMENT_DATA;
    
    // SOMEWHERE HERE YOU ADD LOOP THROUGH YOU DATA, IF ITEM HAS MORE DATA THAN THE NUMBER OF COLUMNS AVAILABLE, CALL AddColumn passing column name.
      addColumn(new_column) {
         this.columnsToDisplay.push(new_column);
        this.displayedColumns.push(new_column);
      }
```

Html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
</table>
```

Angular material dynamic table:
https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: I can't open your link, but I'm trying to follow your sample

Comment: I added link to Angular material reference, they have a good sample of dynamic tables.

Comment: I see that your solution works, but I'm having issues in display data